# Layout differences between Qt Designer and running program

Tags: qt, layout, qt-designer

I am trying to make a basic wireframe design before I add colours, etc. As seen in the two pictures below, the sizing of the layouts is very different in designer and when the program is run. I have tried changing the layout stretch but it has no effect.

Designer:

[image: Designer view]

Running program:

[image: Running program view]

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide what should happen when the window is resized larger than the size shown in Qt Designer. Presumably, you don't want the "Logo" and "Date" rows to expand to take up the extra vertical space, and you don't want the "Modules" row to expand either. So the extra space will have to go at the bottom.

The simplest way to achieve that is to put an expanding spacer immediately below the "Modules" row, but inside the outer layout. This will push everything up against the top of the window, and only allow space to grow at the bottom.